# Paypal PLUS on behalf of merchant

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-plus

Is it possible to open the Paypal REST-API for authorizing a Paypal-PLUS payment in such a way that the payment is made on behalf of a merchant?

Reason:
- we are a shop-hoster and every merchant has a shop with us.
- It would be awkward if every merchant had to create his own paypal-developer account just to get a ClientId and ClientSecret.

So is it possible to make the payment on behalf of a merchant, as it is already possible with Paypal-Express, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use PayPal Plus a merchant must apply for it and get approved after a vetting procedure with PayPal.  As such, I do not believe this is going to be available for 3rd party permission requests.

Comment: But it is possible with the paypel REST-api to make payments on behalf of the merchant... See:

Link1: https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2017/01/03/setting-payee/

Link2: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreateThirdPartyPayment.html

i tested it with my local sandbox-environment, and i can also act on behalf of the merchant with help of the "payee-object". This also seems to work with paypal-plus... So are you sure that its not available? Sandbox has it... but paypal does not document it for paypal-plus specifically. Its unknown territory.

Comment: I'm familiar with the 3rd party permissions, but hadn't specifically tested it with Plus.  If it's working in the sandbox for you then it should work live as well.  Just make sure you specifically test a scenario where your account does have Plus approved and active on it, and the 3rd party merchant account does NOT.  I think what you might find is that you would still get an error in this case because while you have permission to make the call on their behalf, they simply don't have permission to use that product.  It may be that they let the APP be the owner of the approved Plus feature.

Comment: this is a good test. Thx.
But it seems i can really test it only in a Live-Environment (not Sandbox). Because paypal explicitly states: "...By default, PayPal PLUS is enabled for all German sandbox accounts...". See: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-plus/germany/

But maybe if i have time i will try to test it.